# Как отсортировать массив html элементов по высоте?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

В консоли получаю это, и собственно как их отсортировать?
И также, как "законектить" каждый дочерний div с его высотой?

```
NodeList(5) [div.arrayPart, div.arrayPart, div.arrayPart, div.arrayPart, div.arrayPart]
```

```
mainContainer.querySelectorAll('div')
```

[image: divs]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var sorted = [...mainContainer.querySelectorAll('div')].sort(
  (a, b) => a.offsetHeight - b.offsetHeight
);
sorted.forEach(item => item.parentNode.appendChild(item));
```